# Prove the $\ Det A$ is nonzero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $A$ is an nxn matrix, then if we have $|Ah|\geq c|h|$ for some positive $c$, can we say $A$ is invertible? Notice that $|.|$ is the Euclidean norm!

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is invertible if it has trivial kernel. If for every nonzero $h$ we have $|Ah|\geq c|h|$, in particular $Ah\neq 0$, so $A$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: It is correct, I only thought it was the product of eigenvalues, thanks!

Comment: @DavidMao Sure, no problem.